# Why does this node.js app runs locally by Heroku however is not loading in Heroku?

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I'm trying to deploy an app for the first time using Heroku, after successfully committing the repo and pushing to the changes to Heroku, the app still doesn't load.

Heroku Logs:

```js
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 06: 06.898178 + 00: 00 heroku[web .1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 06: 06.806047 + 00: 00 app[web .1]: npm ERR!missing script: start
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 06: 06.820983 + 00: 00 app[web .1]:
  2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 06: 06.821278 + 00: 00 app[web .1]: npm ERR!A complete log of this run can be found in:
  2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 06: 06.821337 + 00: 00 app[web .1]: npm ERR!/app/.npm / _logs / 2020 - 03 - 04 T11_06_06_806Z - debug.log
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 06: 06.881460 + 00: 00 heroku[web .1]: Process exited with status 1
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 09: 27.000000 + 00: 00 app[api]: Build started by user freecorpteam @gmail.com
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 09: 40.461743 + 00: 00 app[api]: Deploy b856e1a0 by user freecorpteam @gmail.com
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 09: 40.461743 + 00: 00 app[api]: Release v11 created by user freecorpteam @gmail.com
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 09: 40.921846 + 00: 00 heroku[web .1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 09: 40.000000 + 00: 00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 09: 43.094952 + 00: 00 heroku[web .1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 09: 45.156685 + 00: 00 heroku[web .1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 09: 45.097670 + 00: 00 app[web .1]: npm ERR!missing script: start
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 09: 45.102936 + 00: 00 app[web .1]:
  2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 09: 45.103180 + 00: 00 app[web .1]: npm ERR!A complete log of this run can be found in:
  2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 09: 45.103338 + 00: 00 app[web .1]: npm ERR!/app/.npm / _logs / 2020 - 03 - 04 T11_09_45_098Z - debug.log
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 09: 45.139795 + 00: 00 heroku[web .1]: Process exited with status 1
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 11: 52.000000 + 00: 00 app[api]: Build started by user freecorpteam @gmail.com
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 12: 05.304994 + 00: 00 heroku[web .1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 12: 05.046524 + 00: 00 app[api]: Deploy 44 da3cc6 by user freecorpteam @gmail.com
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 12: 05.046524 + 00: 00 app[api]: Release v12 created by user freecorpteam @gmail.com
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 12: 07.607259 + 00: 00 heroku[web .1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 12: 05.000000 + 00: 00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 12: 09.990662 + 00: 00 heroku[web .1]: State changed from starting to up
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 12: 09.637412 + 00: 00 app[web .1]:
  2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 12: 09.637434 + 00: 00 app[web .1]: > airbnb @1 .0 .0 start / app
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 12: 09.637434 + 00: 00 app[web .1]: > node index.js
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 12: 09.637435 + 00: 00 app[web .1]:
  2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 12: 09.804031 + 00: 00 app[web .1]: server is running
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 14: 33.000000 + 00: 00 app[api]: Build started by user freecorpteam @gmail.com
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 14: 46.829363 + 00: 00 heroku[web .1]: Restarting
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 14: 46.832814 + 00: 00 heroku[web .1]: State changed from up to starting
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 14: 46.617874 + 00: 00 app[api]: Deploy ebc34190 by user freecorpteam @gmail.com
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 14: 46.617874 + 00: 00 app[api]: Release v13 created by user freecorpteam @gmail.com
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 14: 47.000000 + 00: 00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 14: 47.874543 + 00: 00 heroku[web .1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 14: 47.977184 + 00: 00 heroku[web .1]: Process exited with status 143
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 14: 49.232441 + 00: 00 heroku[web .1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 14: 51.656608 + 00: 00 heroku[web .1]: State changed from starting to up
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 14: 51.560969 + 00: 00 app[web .1]: server is running
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 20: 46.000000 + 00: 00 app[api]: Build started by user freecorpteam @gmail.com
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 20: 59.379726 + 00: 00 app[api]: Deploy b253d4d4 by user freecorpteam @gmail.com
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 20: 59.379726 + 00: 00 app[api]: Release v14 created by user freecorpteam @gmail.com
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 21: 00.304391 + 00: 00 heroku[web .1]: Restarting
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 21: 00.308413 + 00: 00 heroku[web .1]: State changed from up to starting
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 20: 59.000000 + 00: 00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 21: 01.360046 + 00: 00 heroku[web .1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 21: 01.466415 + 00: 00 heroku[web .1]: Process exited with status 143
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 21: 03.924313 + 00: 00 heroku[web .1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 21: 06.294179 + 00: 00 app[web .1]: server is running
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 21: 07.763819 + 00: 00 heroku[web .1]: State changed from starting to up
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 30: 52.000000 + 00: 00 app[api]: Build started by user freecorpteam @gmail.com
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 31: 06.009751 + 00: 00 heroku[web .1]: Restarting
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 31: 06.013344 + 00: 00 heroku[web .1]: State changed from up to starting
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 31: 05.790725 + 00: 00 app[api]: Deploy bd9bf403 by user freecorpteam @gmail.com
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 31: 05.790725 + 00: 00 app[api]: Release v15 created by user freecorpteam @gmail.com
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 31: 07.206890 + 00: 00 heroku[web .1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 31: 07.283478 + 00: 00 heroku[web .1]: Process exited with status 143
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 31: 06.000000 + 00: 00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 31: 07.922427 + 00: 00 heroku[web .1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 31: 09.697432 + 00: 00 app[web .1]:
  2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 31: 09.697448 + 00: 00 app[web .1]: > airbnb @1 .0 .0 start / app
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 31: 09.697449 + 00: 00 app[web .1]: > node index.js
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 31: 09.697449 + 00: 00 app[web .1]:
  2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 31: 09.841347 + 00: 00 app[web .1]: server is running
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 31: 10.158006 + 00: 00 heroku[web .1]: State changed from starting to up
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 39: 27.000000 + 00: 00 app[api]: Build started by user freecorpteam @gmail.com
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 39: 40.313098 + 00: 00 app[api]: Deploy 5 d445be2 by user freecorpteam @gmail.com
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 39: 40.313098 + 00: 00 app[api]: Release v16 created by user freecorpteam @gmail.com
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 39: 40.000000 + 00: 00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 39: 41.143634 + 00: 00 heroku[web .1]: Restarting
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 39: 41.161325 + 00: 00 heroku[web .1]: State changed from up to starting
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 39: 41.887182 + 00: 00 heroku[web .1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 39: 41.956999 + 00: 00 heroku[web .1]: Process exited with status 143
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 39: 43.484238 + 00: 00 heroku[web .1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 39: 45.834243 + 00: 00 app[web .1]: server is running
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 39: 46.339851 + 00: 00 heroku[web .1]: State changed from starting to up
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 41: 00.000000 + 00: 00 app[api]: Build started by user freecorpteam @gmail.com
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 41: 13.457898 + 00: 00 heroku[web .1]: Restarting
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 41: 13.473960 + 00: 00 heroku[web .1]: State changed from up to starting
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 41: 12.858989 + 00: 00 app[api]: Deploy 7357470 a by user freecorpteam @gmail.com
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 41: 12.858989 + 00: 00 app[api]: Release v17 created by user freecorpteam @gmail.com
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 41: 13.000000 + 00: 00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 41: 14.845852 + 00: 00 heroku[web .1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 41: 14.948458 + 00: 00 heroku[web .1]: Process exited with status 143
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 41: 17.987602 + 00: 00 heroku[web .1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 41: 21.528516 + 00: 00 app[web .1]: server is running
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 41: 22.657768 + 00: 00 heroku[web .1]: State changed from starting to up
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 48: 56.000000 + 00: 00 app[api]: Build started by user freecorpteam @gmail.com
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 49: 10.202399 + 00: 00 heroku[web .1]: Restarting
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 49: 10.205603 + 00: 00 heroku[web .1]: State changed from up to starting
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 49: 09.824296 + 00: 00 app[api]: Deploy 9 dbe0b02 by user freecorpteam @gmail.com
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 49: 09.824296 + 00: 00 app[api]: Release v18 created by user freecorpteam @gmail.com
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 49: 10.000000 + 00: 00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 49: 11.335018 + 00: 00 heroku[web .1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 49: 11.464510 + 00: 00 heroku[web .1]: Process exited with status 143
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 49: 11.944025 + 00: 00 heroku[web .1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 49: 13.650108 + 00: 00 heroku[web .1]: State changed from starting to up
2020 - 03 - 04 T11: 49: 13.488186 + 00: 00 app[web .1]: server is running
```

**index.js**

```js
const bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
 express = require('express'),
 app = express();

// Setting up the app
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// ================= Display routes ==================

// === Root route ===

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
 res.render('home');
});

app.get('/blog', function(req, res) {
 res.render('blog');
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT, function() {
 console.log('server is running');
});
```

**package.json**

```js
{
 "name": "airbnb",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "description": "Airbnb guide",
 "main": "index.js",
 "scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  "start": "node index.js"
 },
 "author": "Freedom Corporation",
 "license": "ISC",
 "dependencies": {
  "ejs": "^3.0.1",
  "express": "^4.17.1"
 }
}
```

**Procfile**

```js
web: node index.js
```

The app runs fine locally, I've tried to add multiple times the start script and also re initialized npm several times.

Thanks,

Comment: Did you use the heroku/nodejs buildpack? It looks like from the logs that your server should be running.

Comment: Hey, thanks,
I followed Heroku's instruction to deploy the app but I haven't used the builpacks. Should I scrap everytjingand do that instead?. Edit: Typo.

Comment: Under settings for your app, look under buildpacks and add the nodejs buildpack. Look here for how to use them https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks

Comment: Thanks, actually now that I'm looking at the settings, I can see that heroku/nodejs was added before. I will read the tutorial, thanks in advance.

Comment: npm is installed. You see a couple of npm errors at the beginning but it later vanishes. Afterwards I don't see anymore errors. Just you pushing new code. The message `server is running` is also displayed within your logs. To me it seems it is working fine. Open your browser, hit `F12` and paste the errors listed there here.

Comment: Try running heroku apps:info and look at the WEB-url is it what you expect?

Comment: Now it seems to be working, I'm not sure what happened, this is embarrassing. Never mind, thank you a lot, @NicolaiMonsMogensen, Tin Nguyen.

Comment: No problems, glad you got it running!